# TextView with too long Strings

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this `layout`

```
<ScrollView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView" />
</ScrollView>
```

When I try to set a too long text, this `Textview` doesn't show that.

```
//OnCreate
//...
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText("..."); //Here is a text with more than 2500
                        //chars and at least have 10 \n char
                        //(it means has at least 10 paragraph)
```

How can do I show that text?

> Edit One :

Even I set a `background` to that `TextView` and the `TextView` does'nt show that background

Comment: Is this your full xml layout? Pull the full code..

Comment: What's the diffrence? The ScrollView is the xml parent.and both have usual properties to math/fill TextView to ScrollView

Comment: check the width and height of your textView, the height should be wrap_content, same with the parent. If the view (or it's parent) is too small it won't show the content

Comment: Thanks Ayoub but does'nt work. if i set a string about 500 chars it's works correctly but when use too long texts, it's like I use setVisibility(View.HIDDEN) and nothing be shown. Even background

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you can set

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

to your textview, so the text which long than your textview will be hide.

Comment: Thanks for your mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Because `android:singleLine="true"` attribute has been deprecated, set the following attributes to your TextView:

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
```

The TextView will then show only the text that can fit to your TextView, followed by an ellipsis `...`

Answer (score 4):

i dont know if this will help you but saw this on developer.android...

> With Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher, you can instruct a TextView to let the text size expand or contract automatically to fill its layout based on the TextView's characteristics and boundaries. This setting makes it easier to optimize the text size on different screens with dynamic content.

```
android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
```

> There are **three** ways you can set up the autosizing of TextView:

[Default](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview#default)

[Granularity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview#granularity)

[Preset Sizes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview#preset-sizes)

=================================================

[readMore](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview#default)

Comment: please add relevant parts from those links here.

Comment: i dont know if this will help you but you have the source here:(https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview#default

Comment: To complement this answer the code should be use like this.         

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

This is found in the doc link above

Answer (score 2):

Use this :

```
  EditText thumbnailView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterBearingNo_editText_id);
    TextView messageView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.string2);
    String text = "LargeText";

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    FlowTextHelper.tryFlowText(text, thumbnailView, messageView, display);
```

`FlowTextHelper.class`

```
class FlowTextHelper {

    static boolean mNewClassAvailable;

    static {
        if (Integer.valueOf(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8) { // Froyo 2.2, API level 8
            mNewClassAvailable = true;
        }

        // Also you can use this trick if you don't know the exact version:
        /*
         * try {
         * Class.forName("android.text.style.LeadingMarginSpan$LeadingMarginSpan2"
         * ); mNewClassAvailable = true; } catch (Exception ex) {
         * mNewClassAvailable = false; }
         */
    }

    public static void tryFlowText(String text, View thumbnailView,
            TextView messageView, Display display) {
        // There is nothing I can do for older versions, so just return
        if (!mNewClassAvailable)
            return;

        // Get height and width of the image and height of the text line
        thumbnailView.measure(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());
        int height = thumbnailView.getMeasuredHeight();
        int width = thumbnailView.getMeasuredWidth();
        float textLineHeight = messageView.getPaint().getTextSize();

        // Set the span according to the number of lines and width of the image
        int lines = (int) Math.round(height / textLineHeight);
        // For an html text you can use this line: SpannableStringBuilder ss =
        // (SpannableStringBuilder)Html.fromHtml(text);
        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text);
        ss.setSpan(new MyLeadingMarginSpan2(lines, width), 0, ss.length(),
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        messageView.setText(ss);

        // Align the text with the image by removing the rule that the text is
        // to the right of the image
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) messageView
                .getLayoutParams();
        int[] rules = params.getRules();
        rules[RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF] = 0;
    }

    public static void tryFlowTextPrice(String text, TextView messageView,
            Display display) {
        // There is nothing I can do for older versions, so just return
        if (!mNewClassAvailable)
            return;

        // Get height and width of the image and height of the text line
        // thumbnailView.measure(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());
        // int height = thumbnailView.getMeasuredHeight();
        // int width = thumbnailView.getMeasuredWidth();
        float textLineHeight = messageView.getPaint().getTextSize();

        // Set the span according to the number of lines and width of the image
        // int lines = (int) Math.round(height / textLineHeight);
        // For an html text you can use this line: SpannableStringBuilder ss =
        // (SpannableStringBuilder)Html.fromHtml(text);
        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text);
        // ss.setSpan(new MyLeadingMarginSpan2(lines, width), 0, ss.length(),
        // Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        messageView.setText(ss);

        // Align the text with the image by removing the rule that the text is
        // to the right of the image
        // LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)
        // messageView
        // .getLayoutParams();
        // int[] rules = params.getRules();
        // rules[RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF] = 0;
    }

}
```